# Chartjs: How to apply updated default options after chart is created?

Tags: typescript, chart.js, vuetifyjs3

I have a dark mode toggle button, and I want Chart.js to respond to the light/dark mode. So I set up two sets of default options:

```js
const defaults = {
  scale: {
    border: {
      color: dark ? '#FFFFFF19' : '#00000019',
    },
    grid: {
      color: dark ? '#FFFFFF19' : '#00000019',
    },
  },
}
```

Whenever the theme mode is changed, `Chart.defaults` is updated, and `chart.update()` is called for each chart. But the new default options are still not applied. How can I apply updated default options after the chart is created?

Here is my setup code:

```js
import {
  CategoryScale,
  Chart,
  LineController,
  LineElement,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  TimeScale,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
} from 'chart.js';
import {merge, remove} from 'lodash';

import type {ChartConfiguration, ChartConfigurationCustomTypesPerDataset, ChartItem, ChartType, DefaultDataPoint} from 'chart.js';

Chart.register(Title, Tooltip, CategoryScale, TimeScale, LinearScale, LineController, PointElement, LineElement);

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
const charts: Array<RmsChart<any, any, any>> = [];

export class RmsChart<
  TType extends ChartType = ChartType,
  TData = DefaultDataPoint<TType>,
  TLabel = unknown,
> extends Chart<TType, TData, TLabel> {
  constructor(item: ChartItem, config: ChartConfiguration<TType, TData, TLabel> | ChartConfigurationCustomTypesPerDataset<TType, TData, TLabel>) {
    super(item, config);
    charts.push(this);
  }

  destroy() {
    super.destroy();
    remove(charts, this);
  }
}

function cssVarColor(variable: string, alpha = 1.0) {
  const cssVar = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue(variable);
  if (!cssVar)
    console.warn(`Cannot get css variable ${variable}`);
  const color = cssVar || '0,0,0';
  return `rgba(${color}, ${alpha})`;
}

async function syncThemeColor() {
  await nextTick();
  const defaults = {
    elements: {
      line: {
        backgroundColor: cssVarColor('--v-theme-chart-primary', 0.12),
        borderColor: cssVarColor('--v-theme-chart-primary', 0.6),
      },
      point: {
        backgroundColor: cssVarColor('--v-theme-chart-point'),
        borderColor: cssVarColor('--v-theme-chart-primary'),
      },
    },
    scale: {
      border: {
        color: cssVarColor('--v-theme-chart-grid', 0.1),
      },
      grid: {
        color: cssVarColor('--v-theme-chart-grid', 0.1),
      },
    },
  };
  merge(Chart.defaults, defaults);
  console.log(charts[0].options);
  for (const chart of charts)
    chart.update();
  console.log('syncThemeColor', Chart.defaults);
}

watch(useIsDarkMode(), syncThemeColor, {immediate: true});
```

I also tried `chart.update()` with different update mode such as 'reset', 'none', 'default' and 'active'. New default options are not applied.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. Since the [scriptable options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/options.html#scriptable-options) are recalculated whenever the chart is updated, I just need to wrap the value in a function. Remember to call `chart.update()` when the theme is changed.

```
  const defaults = {
    // ...
    scale: {
      border: {
        // color: cssVarColor('--v-theme-chart-grid', 0.1),
        color: () => cssVarColor('--v-theme-chart-grid', 0.1),
      },
    },
  };
```